# Cannot read property 'runCLI' of undefined in gulp-jest

Tags: gulp, jestjs, gulp-jest

I am trying to run jest tests with gulp using gulp-jest. 
Installed these packages from npm:

```
"gulp-jest": "^4.0.3", 
"jest-cli": "^25.3.0"
```

and provided the following configuration to jest:

```
"jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "./test/unit-test-coverage",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text",
      "lcov"
    ]
  }
```

I have written a basic method in my gulpfile.js, referred [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jest):

```
function runJsTests() {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
    const __dirname = "Features/Components";
    return gulp.src(__dirname).pipe(jest({
    }));
}
```

However, I am getting the following error when I run the gulp task:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'runCLI' of undefined**

Answer (score 7):

I had the same trouble last friday, to resolve it, I finally had to downgrade version used of jest-cli :

"@types/jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "ts-jest": "24.3.0
    "jest-cli": "24.9.0",
    "jest-html-reporter": "2.5.0",

A bug known on new version of Jest-cli

-> think to remove all node_modules and package_lock.json!

Good luck ;)

Comment: I confirm this fix it. :)

Comment: Jest 25 was released Jan '20 after the latest update came to gulp-jest (over 12 months ago), most likely there was a breaking change.